# GEMM using Numpy einsum

Tags: python, numpy, blas

Can a single numpy einsum statement replicate [gemm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms#Level_3) functionality?  Scalar and matrix multiplication seem straightforward, but I haven't found how to get the "+" working.  In case its simpler, D = alpha * A * B + beta * C would be acceptable (preferable actually)

```
alpha = 2
beta = 3
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
B = A + 1
C = B + 1

left_part = alpha*np.dot(A, B)
print(left_part)
left_part = np.einsum(',ij,jk->ik', alpha, A, B)
print(left_part)
```

Comment: For floating point arrays have a look at [`scipy.linalg.blas`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.blas.html).

Comment: @user6758673 thank for the pointer.  I would still like to know if einsum can do it because einsum has a lot more power and flexibility

Comment: Well `einsum` does multiplication and then sum-reduction (if needed) along an axis/axes. You are performing elementwise addition with that second part. Two different things there.

Comment: The use of `,` for the scalar multiplication is new to me, but it's good that `einsum` handles it logically.  At its core `einsum` is a sum-of-products engine; so sum-without-products is outside of its capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion here: `np.einsum` handles operations that can be cast in the following form: broadcast–multiply–reduce.  Element-wise summation is not part of its scope.

The reason why you need this sort of thing for the multiplication is that writing these operations out "naively" may exceed memory or computing resources quickly.  Consider, for example, matrix multiplication:

```
import numpy as np
x, y = np.ones((2, 2000, 2000))

# explicit loop - ridiculously slow
a = sum(x[:,j,np.newaxis] * y[j,:] for j in range(2000))

# explicit broadcast-multiply-reduce: throws MemoryError
a = (x[:,:,np.newaxis] * y[:,np.newaxis,:]).sum(1)

# einsum or dot: fast and memory-saving
a = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', x, y)
```

The Einstein convention however *factorizes* for addition, so you
can write your BLAS-like problem simply as:

```
d = np.einsum(',ij,jk->ik', alpha, a, b) + np.einsum(',ik', beta, c)
```

with minimal memory overhead (you can rewrite most of it as in-place operations if you are really concerned about memory) and constant runtime overhead (the cost of two python-to-C calls).

So regarding performance, this seems, respectfully, like a case of premature optimization to me: have you actually verified that the split of GEMM-like operations into two separate numpy calls is a bottleneck in your code?  If it indeed is, then I suggest the following (in order of increasing involvedness):

1. Try, carefully!, [`scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.blas.html).  I would be surprised if you get
     significantly better performance, since `dgemm`s are usually only
     building block themselves.
2. Try an expression compiler (essentially you are proposing
     such a thing) like [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/).
3. Write your own [generalised ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html) using Cython or C.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  As a tangent, my reason for asking was not for performance but instead that einsum can clearly and concisely define very complex linear algebra operations.  I wanted to know if it supported an operation.  I totally agree that premature optimization is bad thing, but it shouldn't be assumed that is the reason for the question and even if it is learning how is often good even if you shouldn't actually do it.  Understanding assembly is useful knowledge, writing assembly is usually a bad idea.  Finally if performance was the reason, dot is way faster than einsum anyways

Comment: I apologize for assuming intent, it is just that it is typically why people want to know this. Also, it was not meant as an insult: taking vectorization too far can mess with your head, at least it did with mine.  I agree that dot is faster for simple matrix multiplications, I just tried to keep the example simple.

Comment: No offense taken.  Thanks again for the answer